# how the python tuple expression print((b,a)[a<b]) gets evaluated

Tags: python-3.x

how the below python3.x expression gets evaluated, how does the answer comes out to be 10 and not a tuple?

## Tuple to showcase Ternary Operator

`a, b = 10,20 
print( (b, a)[a < b] )`
I tried understanding from different sources how does this expression evaluates but didn't get any fine answer.

`a,b=10,20
print( (a, b) [a < b] )` evaluates to 20 i thought it should be 10. how it's getting evaluated?

Comment: (20, 10)[10 < 20] >>> (20, 10)[True] >>> (20, 10)[1] >>> 10

Answer (score 0):

`a < b` is a boolean expression, as such it is evaluated to `True` or `False`. In turn, `True` and `False` are sub-classes of `int` with the values of `1` and `0` respectively.

So `(a, b)[a < b]` evaluates as `(a, b)[0]` if `a > b` and as `(a, b)[1]` if `a < b`.

if `a, b = 10, 20` then `(a, b)[a < b]` evaluates as:

```
(10, 20)[10 < 20]
.
(10, 20)[True]
.
(10, 20)[1]
.
20
```